# Load images data to tensorflow, how to convert tensor strided_slice to string?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have and folder of images, and CSV file that map files's name with labels
I trying to load image and label using TensorFlow following this guide :
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/images#using_tfdata_for_finer_control

After loaded csv file to pandas dataset and tried to modify get_label() to query from ds instead of by folder path, but I can't get the file path from file_path variable

```
pandas dataset:
    IMAGE    LABEL
    AAA.jpg, 1
    BBB.jpg, 2
    CCC.jpg, 3

def get_label(file_path):
    # convert the path to a list of path components
    parts = tf.strings.split(file_path, os.path.sep)
    # The second to last is the class-directory
    one_hot = parts[-2] == class_names
    
    **####I TRIED SOMETHING LIKE THIS BUT NOT WORK, STILL ERROR####:
    print(parts[-1])
    file_name = parts[-1].numpy()
    file_label = df.loc[df['image'] == file_name, 'label'].iloc[0]

    # Integer encode the label
    return tf.argmax(one_hot)

def decode_img(img):
    # convert the compressed string to a 3D uint8 tensor
    img = tf.image.decode_jpeg(img, channels=3)
    # resize the image to the desired size
    return tf.image.resize(img, [img_height, img_width])

def process_path(file_path):
    label = get_label(file_path)
    # load the raw data from the file as a string
    img = tf.io.read_file(file_path)
    img = decode_img(img)
    return img, label

# Set `num_parallel_calls` so multiple images are loaded/processed in parallel.
train_ds = train_ds.map(process_path, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
val_ds = val_ds.map(process_path, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
```

Tried something below, still not work:

```
parts = tf.strings.split(file_path, os.path.sep)
```

parts[-1].numpy() --> errors "attributes not have numpy"
tf.string(pars[-1]) --> still errors

How can I get file_path value, then get label from dataset ?

UPDATE: the trace log

```
Tensor("strided_slice:0", shape=(), dtype=string)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-183-dba8deef1356> in <module>()
      1 # Set `num_parallel_calls` so multiple images are loaded/processed in parallel.
----> 2 train_ds = train_ds.map(process_path, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
      3 val_ds = val_ds.map(process_path, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)

10 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    256       except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    257         if hasattr(e, 'ag_error_metadata'):
--> 258           raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    259         else:
    260           raise

AttributeError: in user code:

    <ipython-input-180-77fcf28e1d68>:19 process_path  *
        label = get_label(file_path)
    <ipython-input-180-77fcf28e1d68>:7 get_label  *
        file_name = parts[-1].numpy()

    AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'
```

Comment: can you include the traceback? Also did you really write `.numpy` or `.numpy()`?

Comment: I mean .numpy(), and also updated traceback.
I print print(parts[-1]), the result is Tensor("strided_slice:0", shape=(), dtype=string)

Comment: try just removing `.numpy()`

Comment: labels in dataset is string, then they can compare, the result is 
IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds

Comment: thats's an error from pandas i think.

Answer (score 0):

I can provide a direct answer to your question but I do not want to encourage a sub-optimal practice.

The 'correct' way of thinking about this is to reorganize your dataset and then use `tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory`

a complete example [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/images)

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem with numpy or pandas as suggested in the comments, but instead has to do with how TensorFlow is designed, ie. it's a feature not a bug. When using tf.data.Dataset, you have to use TensorFlow-only operations where possible, and if you still need heavy string manipulations and such, you could wrap the get_label function with a tf.py_function, although I don't recommend that for all cases, since it does affect the performance of the data loader.

For the time being, here're a few things that might be more suitable:

1. If the amount of images that you have is not too high, and you're OK with the time it takes for reading the images before inputting them into tf.data.Dataset, then you can read the images and labels before using tf.data.Dataset, after which you can read them as

```
tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((images, labels))
```

2. You can also make changes to your image file paths such that they have the labels in their names. Then you can slice the file paths as below to get your labels, then use the last item index-wise (if you put the label at the end of the file name) after splitting to make a one hot encoding of the labels.

```
class_names = ["1", "2", "3"]
def get_label(file_path):
    parts_of_strings = tf.strings.split(file_path, os.path.sep)
    one_hot = parts_of_strings[-2] == class_names  
    # Integer encode the label 
    return tf.argmax(one_hot)
```